# Is this true that $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}(AA^*)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_{n,m}$. Is this true that $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}(AA^*)$?

Comment: Just to be sure,  is $A^*$ the complex conjugate of $A$ for you?

Comment: Rework the proof mentioned by @Yes and see if it can be generalized to $A^*$ instead of $A^T.$

Comment: How to show that $rank(A)=rank(AA^*)$ by using the SVD ? @matt biesecker

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that $A^*$ as a linear transformation is injective on $\text{Im}(A)$, i.e. $\text{ker}(A^*)\cap\text{Im}(A)=0$. Let $v\in\text{ker}(A^*)$. Then for all $w$,
\begin{align*}
\langle A^*v, w\rangle&=0\\
\langle v, Aw\rangle&=0
\end{align*}
So $v\in\text{Im}(A)^\perp$. If $v$ is also in $\text{Im}(A)$, then it must be 0.